# How to control the order of bars in a seaborn barplot

Tags: python-3.x, bar-chart, seaborn

I have a dataframe with 4000+ observations and two columns of interest:  Revenues and cluster_.

[image]

I want to create a barplot with seaborn which I do as follows:

[image]

What I would like now is to order the bars in alphabetical order, i.e., first (foremost left) A+ then A, B+, B, C.

The following command produces a Value Error:

```
sorted_keys = ['A+', 'A', 'B+', 'B', 'C']
data7a.set_index('cluster_').reindex(sorted_keys, axis = 0)

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outdated:

```
sns.barplot(x='cluster_', y='Revenue', data=data7.sort_index())
```

as a plot creation should work.
And if you want an arbitrary order of columns, you can still do

```
sorted_keys = ['C', 'B+', 'A+', 'B', 'A'] # for example
sns.barplot(x='cluster_', y='Revenue', data=data7.reindex(sorted_keys))
```

to have arbitrary ordering you want.

Edit: When using barplot in seaborn, you can pass parameter `order`, so with

```
sns.barplot(x='cluster_', y='Revenue', data=data7, order=['A', 'A+', 'B', 'B+', 'C'])
```

you should be good.

Comment: I get a value error when I do that: See my updated post

Comment: I updated the answer too, you should use the order parameter, which I haven't realized earlier